# Align note text and logo in beamer title slide

Tags: beamer, spacing, footnotes, titles, logos

I have to include a logo and sentence of the supporting funding agency on my title slide. I'd like it to be small, at the bottom and take little space. To do that, I think it would be if the sentence and the logo could be put side-by-side on the same level.

Anybody has an idea how to accomplish that?

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]


\title{Unnecessarily long title}
\author{\small Name 1, Name 2, }
\date{}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{}{\scriptsize Supported by some National Research Fund (LONG FUND NUMBER IN HERE)}
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example.jpg}
}

\begin{document}

  {%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \frame{\titlepage}
  }

\end{document}
```

Which produces the two element above each other and thus takes a lot of space and attention

[image]

Comment: Something like `\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image} \quad \scriptsize\parbox{4cm}{Supported by some National Research Fund (LONG FUND NUMBER IN HERE)} 
}` should result in the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You are already loading the `adjustbox` package, so you could use it to nicely place the image besides the text:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]


\title{Unnecessarily long title}
\author{\small Name 1, Name 2, }
\date{}

\begin{document}

  {%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
      
      \tiny Supported by some National Research Fund (LONG FUND NUMBER IN HERE) \hfill \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{frame}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]